# match string with asterisk

Tags: php, regex

I want to match a string with another via asterisk.

example: i have

```
$var = "*world*";
```

i want to make a function that will either return true or false to match my string. **case insensitive**

```
example:
match_string("*world*","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world*","hello world") // returns false
match_string("*world","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world*","hello world") // returns false
match_string("*ello*w*","hello world") // returns true
match_string("*w*o*r*l*d*","hello world") // returns true
```

the * will just match any character in range. i tried using preg_match for hours with no luck.

Comment: my last try was with the idea of replacing * with (*.) to be able to use preg_match, but dunno what mistake i made.

Comment: Where do you get the strings from? Why not use "normal" regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function match_string($pattern, $str)
{
  $pattern = preg_replace('/([^*])/e', 'preg_quote("$1", "/")', $pattern);
  $pattern = str_replace('*', '.*', $pattern);
  return (bool) preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/i', $str);
}
```

And running it on your test cases above:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: `preg_quote()` should always include the second argument, the delimiter. In this case it should be "/". If you don't include it, `match_string("hello/*", "hello world")` will throw an error.

Comment: `Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead`

Answer (score 2):

```
function match_string($patt, $haystack) {
  $regex = '|^'. str_replace('\*', '.*', preg_quote($patt)) .'$|is';
  return preg_match($regex, $haystack);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
function match_string($match, $string) {
    return preg_match("/$match/i", $string);
}
```

Note that preg_match actually returns the number of matches, but comparing it to true/false works (0 = false, >0 = true). Note the `i` flag at the end of the pattern which makes the match case-insensitive.

This would work for the following examples of yours:

```
example:
match_string("world","hello world") // returns true
match_string(" world","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world ","hello world") // returns false
match_string("ello w","hello world") // returns true
match_string("world","hello world") // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to generate proper regexp. No replace callbacks, no bicycles code

```
$var = "*world*";
$regex = preg_quote($var, '/'); // escape initial string
$regex = str_replace(preg_quote('*'), '.*?', $regex); // replace escaped asterisk to .*?
$regex = "/^$regex$/i"; // you have case insensitive regexp
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7 (too PHP 5.6)

```
<?php

function match_string($pattern, $str)
{
    $pattern = preg_replace_callback('/([^*])/', 'testPRC', $pattern);
    $pattern = str_replace('*', '.*', $pattern);
    return (bool) preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/i', $str);
}

function testPRC($m) {
    return preg_quote($m[1],"/");
}


echo match_string("*world*","hello world"); // returns true
echo match_string("world*","hello world"); // returns false
echo match_string("*world","hello world"); // returns true
echo match_string("world*","hello world"); // returns false
echo match_string("*ello*w*","hello world"); // returns true
echo match_string("*w*o*r*l*d*","hello world"); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `preg_match` or `str_replace` here. PHP has a wildcard comparison function, specifically made for such cases:

> [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch)

Your tests work like expected with `fnmatch()`:

```
fnmatch("*world*","hello world") // returns true
fnmatch("world*","hello world") // returns false
fnmatch("*world","hello world") // returns true
fnmatch("world*","hello world") // returns false
fnmatch("*ello*w*","hello world") // returns true
fnmatch("*w*o*r*l*d*","hello world") // returns true
```

Comment: Note that `fnmatch` uses the wildcard characters that are appropriate to the current OS shell, which may not be what you want. It means the code is not portable without some assumptions about the OS it will run on.